# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Cross Validated's [fourth moderator election](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: gung] [image: Tim]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5682754851176448/0).

Comment: Congratulations to both the new mods! But I hope unsuccessful candidates are not put off from reapplication in any future election.

Comment: I look forward to gung and Tim joining the moderator team.  (We are indeed a team: one of the first things for you guys to do is join the moderator chat room so we can facilitate discussions.)  But I especially want to thank the candidates who were not elected this time: your qualifications are strong, your abilities well-regarded, and I am grateful to all of you for standing in this election.

Comment: Congratulations and thank you to our new mods and thanks to the strong candidates not elected. I had a very hard time deciding between the four of you as I value all of you and the work you did and do for this site immensely.

Comment: Congratulations to the new mods. We had some very strong nominations.

Comment: Congratulations and also many thanks to the other two guys. We had four very competent candidates.

Comment: Thank you to all of the candidates who took the time to put forward a vision for the site.

Comment: Welcome to the team!  Did anyone tell you about the initiation rites?

Comment: Congrats to `grumpy old man` and `Rodak ze Wschodu`. Strong candidates all, indeed.

Comment: Congratulations to gung. I knew you wold be elected and I expect you will do a good job!

Comment: Congrats to both of you, and thank you to everyone who ran.